What adapter do I need to install sprinkler head?
A sprinkler head was damaged and removed by the previous owner but never replaced.  I bought this replacement sprinkler head (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ML3ILG4?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details), but have no idea how to install it to the buried feedline, which is about 1/2 inch in diameter (see attached photo).  What adapter do I need?


The new head screws onto a fitting that has broken off your pipe.  You need to dig out a little more to see exactly what fitting and how to remove the broken one and attach the new one.  You can add a photo to the Question after revealing more of it

What is in the picture is known as a Nipple
You need to dig out a little more dirt and you will find if the nipple is Male/male ( most are) or male / female. You need to remove enough dirt so it doesn't fall into the line while you are working on the repair. A little may be ok, but too much will clog the new sprinkler head or others downline.
Then unscrew the nipple from the line and replace it. You may need to get a nipple extractor tool if it is too difficult to get the nipple removed.
Get a poly nipple made from softer plastic and not a schedule 80 nipple.  The softer poly will break before breaking the main line, if the sprinkler head is impacted. (This is what happened in your case.)
Once you have the nipple of correct height. ( they come in different heights for different sprinkler heads and depth of the main line.) screw in the nipple and then screw in the spray head. Do not use any sealer or teflon tape, it will only break off and clog the sprinkler head. Besides if something leaks, your goal was to get water there anyway.

How can you tell from that photo if this was a screw or barb fitting and if it was direct or on a funny pipe?

On a funny pipe or hard line doesn't matter.  Breaking the soft plastic nipple is common when a sprinkler is impacted.  Barbed fittings are harder/ stiffer and break at the barb to thread area.
